# Problema con creación de Beans en Jboss

Tags: java, java-ee, servidor, jboss, jboss-eap

Al arrancar mi servidor de Jboss 6.4 salta la siguiente traza:

```
16:44:16,720 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/vp301b]] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) JBWEB000287: Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in VFS resource ["/C:/jbossNuevo3/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war/WEB-INF/classes/spring/database.xml"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in VFS resource ["/C:/jbossNuevo3/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war/WEB-INF/classes/spring/database.xml"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jndiDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up datasources/vp301b, service service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.vp301b is not started
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1080) [spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857) [spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543) [spring-context-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3339) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3780) [jbossweb-7.5.7.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.5.7.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.doStart(WebDeploymentService.java:163) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.access$000(WebDeploymentService.java:61) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService$1.run(WebDeploymentService.java:96) [jboss-as-web-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSource' defined in VFS resource ["/C:/jbossNuevo3/jboss-eap-6.4/standalone/deployments/vp301b-ear.ear/vp301b.war/WEB-INF/classes/spring/database.xml"]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'jndiDataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up datasources/vp301b, service service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.vp301b is not started
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1280) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 26 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jndiDataSource': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Error looking up datasources/vp301b, service service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.vp301b is not started
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351) [spring-beans-4.3.16.RELEASE.jar:4.3.16.RELEASE]
    ... 36 more
```

En mi fichero database .xml están definidos cada uno de esos beans, además de ser un código en teoría validado, ya que no fue creado por mi. No sé en que se puede basar el error:

Database.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:jpa="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/jpa/spring-jpa.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd">

    <!-- JNDI DataSource -->
    <jee:jndi-lookup id="dataSource" jndi-name="${jdbc.jndi.name}" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>

    <!-- JPA EntityManagerFactory -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" p:dataSource-ref="dataSource">
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" p:showSql="${hibernate.show_sql}" p:databasePlatform="${hibernate.dialect}" />
        </property>
        <property name="packagesToScan" value="es.xunta.amtega.vp301b"/>
        <property name="jpaProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">${hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto}</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean> 

    <!-- Transaction manager for a single JPA EntityManagerFactory (alternative to JTA) 
    <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" p:entityManagerFactory-ref="entityManagerFactory"/> -->

    <!-- enables scanning for @Transactional annotations -->
    <tx:annotation-driven />

    <!-- Post-processor to perform exception translation on @Repository classes to Spring's DataAccessException hierarchy -->
    <bean class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"/>

    <!-- Spring Data JPA -->
    <jpa:repositories base-package="es.xunta.amtega.vp301b"/>
    <bean id="usernameAuditorAware" class="es.xunta.amtega.transversal.archam.core.data.UsernameAuditorAware" />
    <jpa:auditing auditor-aware-ref="usernameAuditorAware"/>

    <!-- Log de consultas SQL (solo si se activa perfil sql-logger) -->
    <beans profile="sql-logger">
        <jee:jndi-lookup id="jndiDataSource" jndi-name="${jdbc.jndi.name}" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
        <bean id="dataSource" primary="true" class="es.xunta.amtega.transversal.jdbc.logger.DataSourceLogger">
            <property name="dataSource" ref="jndiDataSource" /> 
        </bean> 
    </beans>    

</beans>
```

DataSet en standalone.xml:

```
 <datasource jta="false" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/vp301b" pool-name="vp301b" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:sqlserver://direccionBD</connection-url>
                    <driver-class>com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</driver-class>
                    <driver>sqljdbc41.jar</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>****</user-name>
                        <password>****</password>
                    </security>
                    <validation>
                        <valid-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleValidConnectionChecker"/>
                        <validate-on-match>false</validate-on-match>
                        <background-validation>true</background-validation>
                        <stale-connection-checker class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleStaleConnectionChecker"/>
                        <exception-sorter class-name="org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.extensions.oracle.OracleExceptionSorter"/>
                    </validation>
                    <statement>
                        <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                    </statement>
                </datasource>
```

Comment: verifica que en tu jboss en el archivo standalone.xml exista la referencia del jndi en los datasource

Comment: @JaimeAtriano está referenciado, añado el datasource de standalone.xml a la pregunta, abajo de todo.